# Why is it that we can't write a program that will run on both mac and pc?

Tags: software-distribution

Programming languages are platform independent, so why is it that we can't write a program that will run on both a PC and a Mac?

I want to develop a software and I'm on a mac, but I want it to run on a PC also, is it possible to develop such a software without having to require the user to download a special program that will make my program compatible with their computer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that most software is dependent on the OS to handle some tasks. Yes, most programming languages are compatible with many platforms, but the OS provides a lot of support. When software uses the OS, it is sometimes called making a system call. If you want [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is some more information.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically if you write your program in a 'high level language' it should be portable between two operating systems.

Practically however, the differences start from the very beginning - the API of choice, which works on one and does not on another(Such as, Mac's BSD API is incompatible with Win32 API) and boils down to the very last, which is, executable format, linker and loader. Each operating system has its own quirks.

Then comes the difference between the underlying architecture. Previously Macs ran on PowerPC architecture and Motorola architectures, while PCs used Intel. Since Macs have switched to Intel, there have been attempts at making cross platform executables inside Apple. Most attempts have failed.

There is however a way around your problem. You can use a very high level language such as Python to code and then distribute your python code to your PC friends.(But remember remember, you need a Python interpreter in your PC friends' computers for your program to run). I have successfully ported Python programs from Mac to PC with 0 code changes, and sometimes requiring only 2-4% code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: because language per se is not enough to make an application cross-platform. Also the framework it uses must be cross-platform too, frameworks are required for everything: handling data, displaying things, communicate with the hardware, multi threading, etc

This can usually be done:

- by choosing a complete solution like Java, which will actually run on both platforms seamlessly and even with the same binary
- by using C/C++ and cross platform libraries so that the same program can be compiled for both platforms (keep in mind that you can't distribute the real same binary, you need to compile two in any case)
- by writing the logic of your program just using standard libraries and a standard language and then attach whatever you need for a specific platform just to build two different libraries. Of course you will have to wrap as much as you need so that the cross-platform part of your program doesn't know it

Mind that developing cross-platform applications which are not trivial examples like a game (for which there are plenty of cross-platform APIs) without using a complete solution like Java is not an easy task at all. Especially because most of the GUI you can build are strictly platform specific and relies on their own frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an application to run "anywhere" your best option is a JIT type language which means that it compiles as it runs (Just In Time) for the platform that it's on. Really the language that stands out in my mind is Java (there's others and personally I don't like java). However, it's not quite that simple. For example a Window on a Mac computer has pieces and functions that a Window on a PC doesn't have and vice versa. And other operating systems don't even have windows or anything equivilant yet still run Java like Android or iOS for example or countless Linux Distros. And that's just a very basic example it gets MUCH MUCH harrier. Really the best way to build an application that can be used by anyone on just about any device is going web based.

The lesson is that if it was that simple a lot of people wouldn't have jobs and it never will be that simple, things will always progress and change and not everyone is going to want to do the same thing with their OS as someone else. There's a million ways to skin a cat and there's many more ways to implement something in an OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But it is quite tricky. You need to:

- Use a cross platform language (this is the easy part, many languages run on different plaftforms)
- Avoid using any platform-specific features (usually not too hard, but needs testing)
- Ensure you have cross platform libraries for all your dependencies (hard!)

Because of the library issue in particular, there are very few options that work across platforms. Your best options are probably:

- **A JVM language** (like Java, Scala or Clojure) - because the JVM abstracts away from platform specific features, pure Java applications and libraries will run on any platform. Java probably has the best ecosystem of cross platform libraries and tools as a result.
- **JavaScript** - quite a good option if you don't mind running in a browser. There are lots of quirks to deal with, but JavaScript is one of the best cross-platform options because of it's ubiquity.